# How to show all objects from elements inside elements untill the last element in Angular?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

Right at the moment, I am trying to solve a problem I have inside Angular. The problem is that I have one big object, which contains multiple objects of the same type in a array, which also can contain the same objects inside the array of it. I know that it sounds a little complicated but I will try to explain it better in the rest of my text.

```
export class Parameter {
  name: number;
  subject: string;
  type: string;
  comparison: string;
  colour: string;
  givenValue: number;
  tree: string;
  children: Parameter[];
}
```

I already tried a hunderd words/sentences to find someone with the same question but could not find one. Maybe I am trying to explain my question different/not right? I don't know but I am facing this problem for some days an I got rid of it.

Beneath here you can see my HTML code made with angular to see every object in the object and the objects inside. The problem I face is that I am just able to see the first object, and the objects inside that object. But I could not get is so far to let it automatically show all objects untill the end. As you can see I show the second layer in the abject hard coded with a  ngfor.

```
<div class="accordion" *ngFor="let currentParameter of smartContract.parameters">
  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel>

      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          Parameter {{currentParameter.name}}
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div class="parameter">
        <div class="inputs">
          <div class="input">
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select placeholder="Kies een categorie">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories"
                            [value]="category.value"
                            (click)="currentParameter.subject = category.value"
                > {{category.viewValue}} </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let currentParameterOfChild of currentParameter.children" > <!-- dit is de plaats van een nieuwe parameter in een nieuwe laag - begin -->
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            Parameter {{currentParameterOfChild.name}}
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div class="parameter">
          <div class="inputs">
            <div class="input">
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select placeholder="Kies een categorie">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories"
                              [value]="category.value"
                              (click)="currentParameterOfChild.subject = category.value"
                  > {{category.viewValue}} </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="add-parameter-layer">
          <button mat-mini-fab class="plusbutton" [mat-menu-trigger-for]="param1" type="button">
            <mat-icon aria-label="Icon-button with plus">add</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <mat-menu #param1="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item type="button" >
              <span (click)="newParameterNewLayer(currentParameterOfChild.name, currentParameterOfChild.tree)">Nieuwe parameter in nieuwe laag</span>
            </button>
            <button mat-menu-item type="button">
              <span (click)="newParameter()">Nieuwe parameter in deze laag</span>
            </button>
          </mat-menu>
        </div>
      </mat-expansion-panel> <!-- dit is de plaats van een nieuwe parameter in een nieuwe laag - begin -->

      <div class="add-parameter-layer">
        <button mat-mini-fab class="plusbutton" [mat-menu-trigger-for]="param1" type="button">
          <mat-icon aria-label="Icon-button with plus">add</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-menu #param1="matMenu">
          <button mat-menu-item type="button" >
            <span (click)="newParameterNewLayer(currentParameter.name, currentParameter.tree)">Nieuwe parameter in nieuwe laag</span>
          </button>
          <button mat-menu-item type="button">
            <span (click)="newParameter()">Nieuwe parameter in deze laag</span>
          </button>
        </mat-menu>
      </div>

    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

I know, my bad English is very bad and I would like to apologize for this. But I really need help for this right now. I need to show div's inside div's untill I am in the last object how contains variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using recursive components. They are explained in detail [here](https://netbasal.com/recursion-in-angular-components-1cd636269b12).

Roughly explained, you want to use a component inside its own template. Move the code that needs to be run recursively inside its own component and use the component itself there, based on the presence of the `children` property.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-recursive'
   template: `
      <ng-container*ngFor="let child of entry.children">
          <!-- Your content, omitted for readability -->
          <app-recursive *ngIf="child.children && child.children.length > 0" [entry]="child"></app-recursive>
      </ng-container>
   `
})
class AppRecursiveComponent {
   @Input() entry:Parameter;
}
```

Then, inside your template, just use `<app-recursive [entry]="parameterRoot"></app-recursive>`